# How to get unique rows from dataframe, while keeping the one with max value in some column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (from the following csv):

```
load,timestamp,timestr
0,1576147339.49,124219
0,1576147339.502,124219
2,1576147339.637,124219
1,1576147339.641,124219
9,1576147339.662,124219
8,1576147339.663,124219
7,1576147339.663,124219
6,1576147339.663,124219
5,1576147339.663,124219
4,1576147339.663,124219
3,1576147339.663,124219
2,1576147339.663,124219
1,1576147339.663,124219
0,1576147339.663,124219
0,1576147339.673,124219
3,1576147341.567,124221
2,1576147341.568,124221
1,1576147341.569,124221
0,1576147341.57,124221
4,1576147341.581,124221
3,1576147341.581,124221
```

I would like to drop duplicates on the timestamp column, while remaining with the row whose 'load' value is largest.

In this case:

```
load,timestamp,timestr
0,1576147339.49,124219
0,1576147339.502,124219
2,1576147339.637,124219
1,1576147339.641,124219
9,1576147339.662,124219
8,1576147339.663,124219
0,1576147339.673,124219
3,1576147341.567,124221
2,1576147341.568,124221
1,1576147341.569,124221
0,1576147341.57,124221
4,1576147341.581,124221
```

The largest value for 'load' doesn't have to appear first!

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: groupby() + max() ?

Comment: I'm new to pandas, I guess that will do, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `groupby`:

```
print(df.groupby('timestamp', as_index=False)['load'].max().join(df['timestr']))
```

Output:

```
       timestamp  load  timestr
0   1.576147e+09     0   124219
1   1.576147e+09     0   124219
2   1.576147e+09     2   124219
3   1.576147e+09     1   124219
4   1.576147e+09     9   124219
5   1.576147e+09     8   124219
6   1.576147e+09     0   124219
7   1.576147e+09     3   124221
8   1.576147e+09     2   124221
9   1.576147e+09     1   124221
10  1.576147e+09     0   124221
11  1.576147e+09     4   124221
```

Comment: I accepted too soon... I wanted the max ON THE LOAD COLUMN. how do I write that?

Answer (score 0):

reset the precision and display the max with groupby:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format 
df.groupby('timestamp').max()
```

output:

```
                load  timestr
timestamp                    
1576147339.490     0   124219
1576147339.502     0   124219
1576147339.637     2   124219
1576147339.641     1   124219
1576147339.662     9   124219
1576147339.663     8   124219
1576147339.673     0   124219
1576147341.567     3   124221
1576147341.568     2   124221
1576147341.569     1   124221
1576147341.570     0   124221
1576147341.581     4   124221
```